# Treesize not scanning Onedrive local files

Tags: file, onedrive

Treesize free (https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free) is a file / folder analysis tool that quickly scans a PC and sorts folders and files in order of size to quickly show what is using up disk space.

It used to work just fine but sometime in the last few months (I've got a new PC so might be just since having this) I've noticed it has stopped working for OneDrive folders.  We use OneDrive for business at work and all my docs / downloads / desktop etc are backed up on OneDrive, and these folders are all marked to keep offline ("Always keep on this device"), so they are saved locally.

However, Treesize doesn't show these files, apparently I only have 4GB in OneDrive.

[image]

If I right click the OneDrive folder and go to properties, I can see that it is about 60GB.

[image]

Any ideas what's going wrong, or how I could analyse disk space that is used by OneDrive?

- I have the latest version of Treesize and have also tried an older version
- I've tried starting Treesize as admin and as standard

Answer (score 0):

Weird but just if I select an individual folder within Onedrive, it will scan fine.  Just not the whole thing.  So then I tried scanning the full C drive and then go to the Onedrive folder and "Update this branch" and it finished scanning it just fine:

[image]

and updates correctly after that:

[image]

Bit annoying though.  Doesn't explain why it's doing this in the first place